# Optimal way to create shorcut for other package activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, shortcut

I'm trying to create programmability a home shortcut for any installed application.

Considering that the only thing I would have available would the application name, let's say for example the Calculator `com.android.calculator2` (1.5).

I'm using current code bellow, shortcut is created successfully but activity cannot be launched from shortcut (wrong activity class name I guess) and also sometimes the icon seems to be corrupted.

Also add `com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT` to `manifest.xml`.

Is there a optimal way to achieved this?

```
String appName = "com.android.calculator2";
Context newAppContext = null;

// Get other package context
try {
    newAppContext =
        context.createPackageContext(appName, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Create shortcut
if(newAppContext != null) {
    // Get Application Name
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;

    try {
        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(appName, 0);
    } catch (final NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }

    // Get application label
    String applicationName = (String) (ai != null ? pm.getApplicationLabel(ai) : "(unknown)");

    // Shortcut intent
    Intent shortcutIntent  = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    /** Problem in here **
    shortcutIntent.setClassName(newAppContext, newAppContext.getClass().getName());
    *********************/

    shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    // Create intent
    final Intent putShortCutIntent = new Intent();
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, applicationName);
    putShortCutIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, 
                               Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(newAppContext,
                                                                       R.drawable.icon));
    putShortCutIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

    // Broadcast intent
    context.sendBroadcast(putShortCutIntent);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Managed to achieve this by getting the Intent from PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(String packageName).

So:

```
// Intent shortcutIntent  = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
// shortcutIntent.setClassName(newAppContext, newAppContext.getClass().getName());
// shortcutIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
// shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
// shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

Intent shorcutIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get "wrong activity class name", when it cannot find the main activity class in the package. It needs that info so that it can launch the correct Activity in the correct package. So in your example, it should be:

```
shortcutIntent.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "ClassName");
```

I don't know what the `"ClassName"` should be for the Calculator application(maybe you can check its source code), but it should be something like `"com.android.calculator2.MainActivity"`

**EDIT:**
Ok, it seems it is possible to get the  `"ClassName"` dynamically:

```
PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
ResolveInfo info = packageManager.resolveActivity(shortcutIntent, 0);
if(info != null) {
    shortcutIntent.setClassName(info.activityInfo.packageName, info.activityInfo.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LAS_VEGAS, I understand that. But I was wondering how to get the Activity name dynamically and not hard-coded.
Considering that I would only have the package name "com.android.calculator2", from that I can get its ApplicationInfo using PackageManager, but didn't managed to get the package default Activity name.

Comment: Thanks again @LAS_VEGAS, tried your suggestion. The shortcut created would then invoke application dialog to which open the shortcut, maybe I didn't explain myself correctly :)

Well, nevertheless I managed to do what I wanted by getting the Intent from PackageManager instead of manually defining one.
Works fine since I din't intent to modify the shortcut in any way, just add it to home screen as it is.

    Intent shortcutIntent= pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appName);